# Magento 2 products disable hover

Tags: magento, hover, magento2, product

I have Magento 2 Luma theme installed.
I want to remove the hover effect on my products' page and the 'add to cart' button be visible all the time. This works on my homepage but not any other products page.
[image]

My website is www.legowatches.com.au

Any tips really appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: It's about modifying css code. Haven't found the answer anywhere, including magento.stackexchange.com, where they voted also my question off topic...

Comment: No, there's nothing about CSS in your question.Perhaps you should show the CSS in question and say what's going wrong and what you want it to do with respect to the actual CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it.

```css
.products-grid {
    .product-item-info {
        &:not(:hover):not(.active) {
            .product-item-inner {
                position: relative;
                height: auto;
                width: auto;
                border: none;
                box-shadow: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. This should remove hover, not sure about the "addtocart" though.

```
.block.widget .products-grid .product-item 
.product-item-inner, .page-layout-1column 
.block.widget .products-grid .product-item 
.product-item-inner, .page-layout-3columns 
.block.widget .products-grid .product-item 
.product-item-inner {

margin: -1px;
}

.products-grid .product-item-inner {

border: none;
margin: 11px 0 0 2px;
padding: 11px 11px 9px;
position: inherit;
}

.products-grid .product-item-info:hover, 
.products-grid .product-item-info.active {

border: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.abs-visually-hidden-desktop-s, .products-grid 
.product-item-info:not(:hover):not(.active) .product-item-inner {

margin: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [rafaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3430260/rafaga)'s answer and some changes this worked for me

```
& when (@media-common =true) {
 .products-grid {
    .product-item-info {
      &:not(:hover):not(.active) {
        .product-item-inner {
          position: relative;
          height: auto;
          width: auto;
          border: none;
          box-shadow: none !important;
          overflow: unset;
          z-index: 2;
        //   top: 5px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.media-width(@extremum, @break)
  when
  (@extremum = "min")
  and
  (@break = @screen__s) {
  .block.widget .products-grid .product-item .product-item-inner,
  .page-layout-1column
    .block.widget
    .products-grid
    .product-item
    .product-item-inner,
  .page-layout-3columns
    .block.widget
    .products-grid
    .product-item
    .product-item-inner {
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }

  .products-grid .product-item-info:hover .product-item-inner,
  .products-grid .product-item-info.active .product-item-inner {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .products-grid .product-item-inner {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    right: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    position: relative;
    border: none !important;
  }

  .products-grid .product-item-actions {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .products-grid .product-item-info:hover,
  .products-grid .product-item-info.active {
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
}
```

[image]